# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (Python Typeerror)

Tags: python, typeerror

I've got a basic Python script:

```
first_number = float(input("What is your first number?"))
#Ask the user what the first number is before calculation.
second_number = float(input("What is your second number?"))
#Ask the user the second number.
cal = str(input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? You can also 
square, or calculate with each option."))
if cal == "add":
 print("Done! The result is" % first_number + second_number)
 #Checks if the user wants to add, then adds if so. Then prints the final number.
if cal == "subtract":
 print("Done! The result is" % first_number + second_number)
 #Divides and prints.
if cal == "multiply":
 print("Done the result is" % first_number * second_number)
 #Multiplies
if cal == "square":
 print("Done! The result is" % first_number * second_number)
if cal == "divide":
 print("Done! The result is" % first_number / second_number)
 remainder = str(input("Assuming you know the original number, would you like to see 
 the integer remainder? (y/n)"))
 if remainder == "y":
  print("Here you go. The result is" % first_number % second_number)
```

At line 21, it has a weird string formatting error. I'm trying to combine the str in quotes to the remainder math operation, (using the modulo operator) but it's coming up with this weird error: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: `%` is **not** the string concatenation operator. Please read the docs

Comment: `print("Done! The sum is %s" % (first_number + second_number))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to update the string formatting. Assuming you are using Python 3.6 or higher, use F-strings. See [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

[This one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) gives a nice intro.

Also, `input()` returns a string so no need to convert to a string.
Also, indentation. This is a core principle of Python. Learn to do it correct **now**. It's very hard to *unlearn* a way of coding...

```py
first_number = float(input("What is your first number?"))
# Ask the user what the first number is before calculation.
second_number = float(input("What is your second number?"))
# Ask the user the second number.
cal = input("Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide? You can also square, or calculate with each option.")
if cal == "add":
    print(f"Done! The result is {first_number + second_number}")
    # Checks if the user wants to add, then adds if so. Then prints the final number.
if cal == "subtract": # you were adding instead of substracting here
    print(f"Done! The result is {first_number - second_number}") 
    # Divides and prints.
if cal == "multiply":
    print(f"Done the result is {first_number * second_number}")
    # Multiplies
if cal == "square":
    print(f"Done! The result is {first_number * second_number}")
if cal == "divide":
    print(f"Done! The result is {first_number / second_number}")
    remainder = input("Assuming you know the original number, would you like to see the integer remainder? (y/n)")
    if remainder == "y":
        print(f"Here you go. The result is {first_number % second_number}")
```

Comment: I've edited the f string in, working fine. Indentation was messed up when I copy/pasted it out of VS Code, I have it correct in there. I've also removed the `str` from my input, it was a tiny waste of memory. (every bit counts!)